# Android CollaspingToolbarLayout quirks

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to achieve a `CollaspingToolbarLayout` with a `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`, but I'm having issues with rendering of the view on my test device.

[image: no image description]

On scroll it behaves like this, showing a bar above the title.

[image: no image description]

My layout looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="112dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:src="@drawable/login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:layout_collapseMode="none">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/movie_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
            app:layout_collapseMode="none"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#fff"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fff"
            app:tabTextColor="#fff" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/movieviewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: i had the same issue, i fixed it by giving giving `android:layout_marginTop="22sp"` for toolbar

Comment: I'll try that asap

Comment: @Sree no luck still the same

Comment: Do you applied in your Toolbar bar ? try with some other values

Comment: @Sree yeah it just pushed the toolbar title down

Comment: is your `CollapsingToolbarLayout` or `toolbar ` is making problem ? increase the value so will come more down i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/photo"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginTop="15dp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Sample Code: https://goo.gl/iBimYe