# Adding Tablayout and Toolbar to the Top of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

I want to create `DetailActivity` for My app . I want To achieve layout some thing like This .

[image]

Look at to the green rectangle .it is contain  Toolbar and Tablayout .

When we scroll down and when toolbar Touch the Tablayout . They pinned to the top of the screen.

I Think this Layout use the Scroll and ... and use The Toolbar and Tablayout in The Activity .

This is my code where I try to achieve That.but nothing ...

```
DeatailActivity.java

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


import ir.dink.sevom.R;
import ir.dink.sevom.adapters.*;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager detailActivityViewPager;
    private TabLayout detailActivityTabLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        initToolbar();
        initTablayout();
    }

    //============================ Init Toolbar ===================================//
    private void initToolbar() {
        Toolbar mainToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_detail_activity);
        setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    //========================== OnCreate Option Menu =====================================//
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    //=============================== onOption Item Selected ================================//

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.search_action_toolbar:
//                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this ,DetailActivity.class ));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void initTablayout() {
        detailActivityViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager_detail_activity);
        detailActivityTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_detail_activity);
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        DetailActivityPagerAdapter detailadapter = new DetailActivityPagerAdapter(manager);
        detailActivityViewPager.setAdapter(detailadapter);
        detailActivityViewPager.setCurrentItem(detailActivityViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
        detailActivityTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(detailActivityViewPager);
        detailActivityViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(detailActivityTabLayout));
    }


}
```

And This is The Xml of That :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ir.dink.sevom.activities.DetailActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_detail_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_detail"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="124dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_detail_activity"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_hamburger"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_name_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="نام :"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_detail"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_detail"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_count_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="تعداد"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_detail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_name_detail"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_last_update_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="آخرین آپدیت"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_detail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_count_detail"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout_detail_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#4d4d4d"
        android:layout_below="@id/img_detail"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_detail_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout_detail_activity"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you want that tablayout and toolbar do not pinned at the top of the screen?

Comment: You can use [collapsing-toolbar-android](http://d-codepages.com/collapsing-toolbar-android-example/)

Comment: exactly I want when scroll down and when Toolbar touch the tablayout . they pinned to the top of the screen.

Comment: Try using `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` for pinning effect. Check out it's tutorial https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Comment: @Kathi . before this . i use collapsing toolbar . but it have lot of bug for my work .

Comment: @JimitPatel before this . i use collapsing toolbar . but it have lot of problem for my work .

Comment: It's native and I'm too using it. Didn't find any bugs in it. What problems are you facing... Moreover after recent update it is even working even better

Comment: @JimitPatel my mean is problem . and you can see this posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473695/how-can-i-add-the-viewpager-and-tablayout-under-the-collapsing-toolbar-layout?s=13|1.8381 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475906/collapsing-layout-only-collapsed-in-the-collapsing-toolbar-area-not-in-the-other?s=3|0.0000

Comment: Ok for this you will have to add some hack. Because this is not counted in material design (so in short design flaw). I have made one already in one of my app. Will modify that code and post it. But it is not as effective as it should have to be. Still I count it as better than nothing.